# Can access NFS to and from at most 3 (of 5) computers

Tags: rpc, iptables, nfs

I have 5 computers which we will label as such:

1. Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop --> U13.10
2. Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop --> U11.10
3. Raspberry Pi Raspbian --> R1
4. Raspberry Pi Raspbian --> R2
5. Raspberry Pi Raspbian --> R3

I have NFS shares set up like so:

1. U13.10 (192.168.7.1)

   - exporting to U11.10
2. U11.10 (192.168.7.10)

   - importing from U13.10
   - importing from R1 (FAILS)
   - importing from R2
   - importing from R3 (FAILS)
   - exporting to R1
   - exporting to R2
   - exporting to R3
3. R1 (192.168.7.104)

   - importing from U11.10
   - exporting to U11.10
4. R2 (192.168.7.105)

   - importing from U11.10
   - exporting to U11.10
5. R3 (192.168.7.106)

   - importing from U11.10
   - exporting to U11.10

Finally here is the output of my iptables on the server (U13.10) acting as a router:

```
U13.10$ sudo iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:111
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:111
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:2049
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:32803
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:32769
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:892
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:892
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:875
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:875
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:662
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:662
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10000
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10000
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10001
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10001
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10002
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10002
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10003
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10003
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10004
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10004
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10005
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10005
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10006
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10006
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10007
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10007
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10008
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10008
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10009
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:10009
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10002
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10002
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10003
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10003
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10004
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10004
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10005
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10005
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10006
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10006
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10007
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10007
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10009
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:10009
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:6000
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.11         udp dpt:6001
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.12         udp dpt:6002
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.13         udp dpt:6003
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.14         udp dpt:6004
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.15         udp dpt:6005
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.16         udp dpt:6006
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.17         udp dpt:6007
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.18         udp dpt:6008
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.19         udp dpt:6009
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:6000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.11         tcp dpt:6001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.12         tcp dpt:6002
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.13         tcp dpt:6003
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.14         tcp dpt:6004
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.15         tcp dpt:6005
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.16         tcp dpt:6006
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.17         tcp dpt:6007
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.18         tcp dpt:6008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.19         tcp dpt:6009
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7000
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7001
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7002
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7003
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7004
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7005
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7006
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7007
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7008
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         udp dpt:7009
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7002
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7003
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7004
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7005
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7006
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7007
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.7.10         tcp dpt:7009

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

As indicated above, I fail to mount from either R1 or R3. Observe the following output as well, as I think it may be helpful:

```
U11.10$ rpcinfo -p R1
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
U11.10$ showmount -e R1
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)

U11.10$ rpcinfo -p R2
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  39036  status
    100024    1   tcp  35998  status
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  55799  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  55799  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  55799  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  50119  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  50119  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  50119  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp  49361  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  48407  mountd
    100005    2   udp  37991  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  47634  mountd
    100005    3   udp  41386  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  35740  mountd
U11.10$ showmount -e R2
Export list for R2:
/ U11.10

U11.10$ rpcinfo -p R3
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
U11.10$ showmount -e R3
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
```

I can ping R1-R3 from U11.10, and as alluded to earlier I can mount onto R1 and R3 from U11.10. I suspect there is something wrong with my iptables, I just can't figure out why it would let one raspi through, but not the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better ask that on serverfault than on stackoverflow. But to make it short, if i were you, i'd drop ALL my iptables rules first, then check if it works. When you have everything running, check netstat -nap on U11.10 to make sure each process is using the ports you expect it to. Then, re-enable your iptables one by one.

Also, when you try something like the rpcinfo that doesn't work, you might want to have a tcpdump running on your U11.10, and examine the result with wireshark. This gives you an idea if packets are sent, received, and which ports are used, as well.

Comment: I find the subsites of stack exchange are either intended for insanse NASA experts (like ServerFault) or your questions get migrated there after they are far too specific (like ask Ubuntu).